# Casting a vector into a matrix in Python using for-loops

Tags: python, loops, matrix, vector, reshape

I have a list of length 50 created using linspace:

```
m=np.linspace(0,10,50)
```

I can recast this as a 10 X 5 matrix using reshape

```
X=np.reshape(m,(10,5))
```

But, if I want to use for-loops to do the same thing, I get an error:

```
z=np.zeros((10,5),dtype=float)
s=0
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,5):
        m[i][j]=z[s]
        s=s+1
```

here is the error:

> 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

Why isn't the item assignment supported?

Thanks

Comment: What is the variable `m`?  Your code assumes that it's already some 2D structure, but you've never defined it.

Answer (score 1):

`z` will store your items from `m` after the reshape :

```
m=np.linspace(0,10,50)

z=np.zeros((10,5),dtype=float)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(5):
        z[i][j]=m[i * 5 + j]  # compute the index from m base on the current row and column


print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake:

yes, I got the sizes wrong; this is how I rewrote it:

```
m=np.linspace(0,10,50)
z=np.zeros((10,5),dtype=float)
s=0
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,5):
        z[i][j]=m[s]
        s=s+1
```